# practice sql queries with database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle11g, teradata

Is there any site where I can get good database with practice queries to solve. I am seeing a lot on internet, but mostly looks like beginner level.

Comment: -4 and no comments? WTF?

Comment: @Dave - What comments are you looking for? This is off-topic as are all shopping questions. Resource questions are not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Oded: a comment just like yours.

Comment: @Dave - I cast a close vote on this question, though no downvote. I would think that with nearly 4 years of membership you could comment yourself on the unsuitability of the question, instead of what you did comment.

Comment: @Oded: While I agree the question, as it stands, might not fit, if it were reworded, I expect it would get up votes. I was curious about the answer myself. Many questions on this site get shot down for reasons I can't understand, while many similar questions get voted up.

Comment: i dont understand whats harm in asking questions like this.. Many a times questions help in resolving the queries itself....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out SQL Zoo: http://sqlzoo.net/

Comment: thanks man... looks v good to me

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp ... I first started with that then I made up a database with 5 or 6 tables and tried myself subqueries and so on...

Comment: http://w3fools.com - read it and please don't send people to w3schools in the future.

Comment: w3schools may cause permanent brain damage.

Comment: u re right but for the first this tut won't have any harm I guess ... the best is to look at http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/tutorial/DBXETutorial/index.htm to get the background of databse ....